# The physics of the deodorant spray bottle volume

Tags: everyday-life

I noticed that deodorant (or anti-transpirant) spray bottles (pressurized?) usually contain $150~\text{ml}$, max $200~\text{ml}$ (that I've seen; although *I think* I spotted some $300~\text{ml}$ on the Chinese internet).

Is there a *physics* reason for this (not being larger)?

[image]

(For example, and just guessing wildly, could it be that larger bottles are dangerous at certain mountainous heights?? Or larger bottles have a "spraying pressure" that is not constant enough??)

PS: Note the quantum bit in the product name. :)

Comment: Probably not. I mean, in all likelihood they could make them bigger, but figured it'd be more business-efficient to market them in the size they are, similar to how Coca-Cola doesn't sell their sodas in 5-gallon cans; it's not because they couldn't do it, it's because no one would buy them.

Comment: It's mostly marketing. Very small cans and very large cans have been made, but they aren't as popular. The small cans aren't cost effective because you're paying for a smaller contents to can ratio, and the large cans are too difficult for people to hold and use. The current can size is the result of much experimenting by a horde of marketing departments. If people's preferences change in the future then no doubt the can sizes will too.

Comment: @JohnRennie OK, so nothing physicsy like weaker structure/dangerous expansion/etc. Sure about that? PS: A couple of weeks ago I saw a $1~\text{l}$ beer can. :) Shotgun, anyone?

Comment: @aufkag: the pressure in aerosol cans is only 3-5 atmosphere's so they don't make that big a bang if they burst (I'm assuming you're not putting it in a fire to burst it :-). Where I worked we had a machine that punctured anti-perspirant cans so they could be disposed of safely, and while the cloud of released AP was quite spectacular the can itself didn't do anything impressive.

Comment: @JohnRennie I will not ask where you worked, but you lot must have been working very hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It's mostly marketing. Very small cans and very large cans have been made, but they aren't as popular. The small cans aren't cost effective because you're paying for a smaller contents to can ratio, and the large cans are too difficult for people to hold and use. The current can size is the result of much experimenting by a horde of marketing departments. If people's preferences change in the future then no doubt the can sizes will too. –  John Rennie
>
> @aufkag: the pressure in aerosol cans is only 3-5 atmosphere's so they don't make that big a bang if they burst (I'm assuming you're not putting it in a fire to burst it :-). Where I worked we had a machine that punctured anti-perspirant cans so they could be disposed of safely, and while the cloud of released AP was quite spectacular the can itself didn't do anything impressive. –  John Rennie